# Using HREF to send variable to PHP fopen

Tags: php, href, fopen

I know very little about coding. I have what is probably a very basic question. I want to use various links on page A to tell page B which text file to display using PHP.

I can use PHP on page B to display a specifically named file. E.g.

```
$f = fopen("first_file.txt", "r");
// Read line by line until end of file
while(!feof($f)) {
echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
}
fclose($f);
```

But I don't want to create and store hundreds of pages, one for each text file I want to display. I'd prefer to create page B as a kind of template and populate its text (from a text file) using a variable somehow conveyed by a link from page A.

Someone told me to use something like this on page A (which could be completely wrong):

```
<a href="pageB.php?txtfile:first_file.txt">First Text</a> 
<a href="pageB.php?txtfile:second_file.txt">Second Text</a>, etc.
```

But I don't know how to alter the PHP code on page B to grab the variable from the link on page A. Any help out there?

Comment: Oh god no. **MASSIVE** security issue. DO NOT ATTEMPT.

Answer (score 0):

firstly its

```
<a href="pageB.php?txtfile=first_file.txt">First Text</a>
```

equals not colon

then the variable is in `$_GET['txtfile']`

so its

```
$f = fopen($_GET['txtfile'], "r");
```

***SECURITY WARNING, any one could access any file on your server if you do this by adding the file name they want to the url***

For example, somebody might decide to request this URL:

```
pageB.php?txtfile=../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

---

an alternative approach:

```
 <a href="pageB.php?txtfile=1">First Text</a>
```

on pageB.php:

```
$files=array('1'=>'file1.txt','2'=>'file2.txt');
$f = fopen($files[$_GET['txtfile']], "r");
 ...
```

if the file list is huge you may want to use a db to manage it.

Comment: Just thought that should be emphasized more :)

Comment: good idea @David, i'm inclined to remove everything except the warning as an answer

Comment: So how should I display the text from the files?

Comment: there are a few options -how about `txtfile=1` then have an array matching the id (1) to the list of files `$f=array('1'=>'file1.txt',);`

Comment: OK, I was thinking about that. So
    $f=array('1'=>'file1.txt',);
    $f=array('2'=>'file2.txt',);
    etc.
    $f = fopen("first_file.txt", "r");
    // Read line by line until end of file
    while(!feof($f)) {
    echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }
fclose($f);

Comment: I'll have about 300 text files eventually. But it will start small. 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i would start using a db at some point for the file names, but that can be added latter -.